# Создание пользователей Active Directory через Power Shell

Tags: powershell

Создаю пользователей для AD из CSV файла следующим образом:

```
Import-Csv "С:\путь_к_файлу" -Delimiter ";" | ForeEach-object { `
$DisplayName = $_.SamAccountName + "@domain.test"
$Uname = $_.Surname + " " + $_.GiveName + " " + $_.Initials

New-ADUser `
-Name $Uname `
-DisplayName $Uname `
-GiveName $_.GiveName
... и так далее
}
```

В CSV файле значения столбцов такие же как для командлета `New-ADUser` а вот описание, например имя, пишу на русском и при создании этих пользователей естественно русские символы отображаются некорректно.
Вопрос такой: как сделать отображение русских символов корректными, ведь когда создаю через ГУИ все русские символы корректны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну собственно чуть покопался и обнаружил такой параметр как `-Encoding`. Задав ему параметр `default` русский текст из файла отображается корректно.

Получается следующее `Import-Csv "С:\путь_к_файлу" -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Default` ...